# Problema con Entity Framework en Visual Studio 2013!

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, wpf

Lo que sucede, que al momento de generar la conexion a la BD con Entity Framework no me sale el EF Designer, ¿A que se deberá?

[image: vis]

Comment: El título de tu pregunta debería ser indicio objetivo del problema que enfrentas, considera editarlo

Comment: @Aprendiz y sabes la posible solución a eso? a lo que puse

Comment: Mira si [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34330987/579895) puede ayudarte